# PDE System and Analytic Functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, analyticity, analytic-functions

Please, could someone give me some help with this problem? I've struggling for days on it.

> Let $a, b_{i j}$ be analytic functions defined in a neighborhood of
>   $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi ,\psi$ analytic in a neighborhood of
>   $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. In a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
>   consider
>    $$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} u_t + au_x + b_{11}u + b_{12}v
>  =  f, \\ v_x + b_{12}u + b_{22}v =  g, \end{array} \right. $$
>
> with the condition
>
> $ u(x,0)= \varphi(x) \,\,\ \mathrm{e} \,\,\ v(0,t) =
>  \psi(t) $
>
> $(a)$ Let $(u, v)$ be a smooth solution in a neighborhood of origin.
>   Prove that all derivatives of $u$ and $v$ at $0$ are expressed in
>   terms of those of $a$,  $b_{ij}$,  $f$,  $g$,  $\varphi$ e $\psi$ in
>   $0$.
>
> $(b)$ Prove that there is an analytical solution $(u,v)$ in a
>   neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

**My Attempt:** I got the following ideias

1)$u_x(0)$=$\varphi_x(0)$ in any order, cuz I am over the initial condition.

2)$v_t(0)$=$\psi_t(0)$ in any order, cuz I am over the initial condition, as well.

3) When making the other derivatives I need to use the equations given in the system. But I couldn't get it.

I also have no clue about how to solve letter (b).

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.